# How to edit div elements and style them (from the UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm really trying to achieve or at least know how it is done is how canva.com works, how that editor works.
An reference example can be this link [Canva resume creator](https://www.canva.com/design/play?category=tACZCki4tbY)

Comment: Two links that can help you: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_drawing.asp

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a complete answer, but you can use the [Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/apps/) browser extension to spy what technos are used on a website.

Here is the Wappalyser rapport for the website you linked :

[image: Wappalyzer]

You might be interested by the [MobX Wappalyzer page](https://www.wappalyzer.com/technologies/javascript-libraries/mobx) or the [MobX website](https://mobx.js.org/)